Why my ECS can't pull images from my ECR?
I use terraform to start ECS and ECR, and I successfully pushed my image into ECR. But when my ECS try to pull image from ECR, it seems to have reported a network-related problem.
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://api.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443: i/o timeout. Please check your task network configuration.

Here's my network.tf:
resource "aws_security_group" "myProject" {
  name   = "${terraform.workspace}-myProject"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "openSearch" {
  name   = "${terraform.workspace}-opensearch"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

# ssh
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ssh_ingress" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.myProject.id
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

# OpenSearch
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "myProject_ingress_opensearch" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 443 
  to_port                  = 443
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.myProject.id
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.opensearch.id
}

# 
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "myProject_egress" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 443
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.myProject.id
}

Did I miss anything? I'm a newbie of terraform and aws, please help me, thank you all.
How to write a correct network.tf

What kind of subnet is the task in? Does it have a route to an IGW or a NAT?

What are the permissions assigned to the ECS task? Can you share that as well?

Permissions aren't the issue, because the error is an i/o timeout, not an IAM error.

At true, my bad, was quick to ask the question.

It looks like a problem with your subnets. Your ECS cluster is deployed in a private subnet. So to have access to ECR from a private subnet you have 2 options: add NAT gateway for the private subnet or add VPC endpoints to ECR.
Example of vpc_with_nat.tf.
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
  vpc = true
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.nat.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private.id
}


